# How do I plot a line graph based off the 'Type' column? I want a line for A and line for B based off the 'Price' Column

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, charts

How would I create a line chart that has a line for A and line for B based off the common dates that are in the index?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Type':['A','A','B','B','A','A','B','B'],'Price':[12,14,11,15,17,15,9,16]}, index=['2019-01-02', '2019-01-03','2019-01-04','2019-01-05','2019-01-06','2019-01-07','2019-01-08','2019-01-09'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
df.pivot(columns = 'Type').interpolate().plot()
```